# getting id from post request

Tags: php, html

i'm trying to make CMS with  PHP

i need to get the if from post request

```
<form action="updatevideo.php" method="post" role="form">

    Title:      <input name="title" type="text" required> <br />
    description:<input name="desc" type="text"  required> <br />
    url:        <input name="ytl" type="text"  required> <br />
    <input type="hidden"  name="id"  />
    <input type="submit" name="addVideo" value="Add New Video" />
</form>
```

how can i make this input's value = **id**

```
    <input type="hidden"  name="id"  />
```

on control page

```
public function Update()
{
    /*
        1-get data into variables 

        2-validation

        3-Database
    */

    if(isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id']>0)
    {

        $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
        $user = $this->videoModel->Get_By_Id($id);
        print_r($user);
        echo
        '
        <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
             <title>Page Title</title>
             </head>
                <body>

                    <form action="updatevideo.php" method="post" role="form">

                       Title:      <input name="title" type="text" required> <br />
                       description:<input name="desc" type="text"  required> <br />
                       url:        <input name="ytl" type="text"  required> <br />
                                   <input type="hidden"  name="id"  />
                                   <input type="submit" name="addVideo" value="Add New Video" />
                    </form>

                </body>
            </html>
           ';        
    }


    else
    {


        if(isset($_POST['addVideo']))
        {
            $id    = $_POST['id'];
            echo "5ara" ;
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $desc  = $_POST['desc'];
            $url   = $_POST['ytl'];

            //Validation

            $vid = $this->getVid($url); //video id -_-
            $data = array(

                'title'      => $title,
                'desc'       => $desc,
                'vid'        => $vid
           );



           if($this->videoModel->Update($id,$data))
           {
               System::Get('tpl')->assign('message','User Updated');
               System::Get('tpl')->draw('success');
           } 


           else
           {
               System::Get('tpl')->assign('message','Error Updating User');
               System::Get('tpl')->draw('error');                   
           }
        }


        else
        {
           System::Get('tpl')->assign('message','NO USER CHOSEN');
           System::Get('tpl')->draw('error');                
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You missed out the value in **<input type="hidden"  name="id"  VALUE='x' />**

Comment: You have to declare the value parameter. Edit: Wooops, too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple really. As you checked it exists and moved it into a variable you can just echo the `$id` into the `value` attribute of that input tag.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '" />
```

Using your code:

```
echo '
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <title>Page Title</title>
     </head>
     <body>

          <form action="updatevideo.php" method="post" role="form">

               Title:      <input name="title" type="text" required> <br />
               description:<input name="desc" type="text"  required> <br />
               url:        <input name="ytl" type="text"  required> <br />
              <input type="hidden"  name="id" value="' . $id . '" />
                               <input type="submit" name="addVideo" value="Add New Video" />
           </form>
      </body>
      </html>';
```

Comment: yes bro i think you understand me now the problem when i tried to echo $id the result is $id not real value of the id \ :(

Comment: It must be, nothing appears to change `$id` after you assign `(int)$_GET['id']` to it. Make sure the `id` parameter in URI string is proper.

Comment: yes there is problem :( what exactly i need to do ( $id = (int)$_GET['id']; ) so it will get the id from the url then <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id" /> i want the value be $id = (int)$_GET['id'] then when the user click submit id will be $id = $_POST['id']; the id that gotten from the source from the get request :)

Comment: That is what should happen with the above code. You are echo'ing using a single quoted string so you have to have the `end single quote` then the `dot` concatenator the the `$id` and then the `dot` concatenator and finally open the `single quoted string` again

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/MnWdRLt.png from Get request ...then from post request i can't get the id http://i.imgur.com/nNnBtXR.png

Comment: i but can i ask you for more clarification about the dots "  $id  " why can't i type it in that way ?? in php when i type $x = 1 ; echo $x ; the result is 1 !?

Comment: If you were using a doublequoted string literal you can because then PHP expands $var to be the contents of $var. But in a singlequoted string it does not. HOWEVER you are using double quotes around the tab attributes i.e.`name="id" type="hidden"`so you cannot use a double quoted string literal, as this would keep starting and stopping the string literal itself. The way you are doing it is in my opinion the best/most easy to read way

Comment: ok i understand now thanks ,,, another thing if you don't mind please check pastebin.com/PUaP9AbC when i try to echo the another design it doesn't work do you know the reason ? http://imgur.com/d2CZkVL

Answer (score 1):

Edited due to question edit.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'" />
```

You echo a big block of text, this way you can concatenate the `$id` by stopping block output, including `$id` and resuming block output.

Comment: Look at the edit  i need the value be variable the contain the id from the request

Comment: Edited accordingly :)

Comment: You just need to use concatenation as shown in my answer.

Comment: ok bro look what exactly i need to do ( $id = (int)$_GET['id']; ) so it will get the id from the url then <input type="hidden"  name="id" value="$id" /> i want the value be $id = (int)$_GET['id'] then when the user click submit id will be $id    = $_POST['id']; the id that gotten from the source from the get request :)

Answer (score 1):

> Define the VALUE attribute :

`<input type="hidden"  name="id"  value="ID_VALUE"/>`

OR if you have id in varible than use below code :

`<input type="hidden"  name="id"  value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>`

OR
As you are using the HTML in PHP than:

`<input type="hidden"  name="id"  value="'.$id.'"/>`

> ID_Value should be your id like 1,2,3..etc.
>
> And Get the id on Action page :

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

> Apart from this you have mention **POST** in form method and on your
>   action page you are trying to get the values using **GET** method,
>   which is wrong.

Comment: value="ID_VALUE" yes ok but i need to make ID_VALUE variable that contain the id

Comment: Check updated answer, if you want to give value using php variable.